# Clear collection object or retrieve last item

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a clear method to remove all items for a collection object in vba? Like

```
colObj.clear
```

because having to loop through entire thing to clear all is ;_;

Alternatively, is there a last item method like `colObj.lastitem` or do I have to `colObj.count` to get last item then something like `colObj.item(colObj.count-1)` to get second to last item?

My search suggests there is no such methods I seek but then again `name` is no longer documented but it still works. And yes, I already tried `.clear` XD

Or if anyone knows a better way to close **certain** open workbooks please offer suggestions.

Edit: perhaps during the `for each i in colObj` loop of whatever actions I need to take, I can put `colObj.remove i` at the very end? Essentially deleting items as I go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no Clear method, but to clear the collection you can do this:

```
Set colObj = New Collection
```